# Consider defining a bean of type 'Dao interface' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am planning to break all the DAO layer code into a separate Spring boot data project.
So I created two projects one of which will have all the database related code and the other will have service code which will then use the first project as a dependency to interact for any database-related actions.

Project1: DatabaseInteractionService
Project2: InsuranceCleanupService

**InsuranceCleanupService startup class**

```
package com.ics;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.ms.base.entity", "com.dis", "com.dis.config", "com.dis.dao", "com.dis.dao.Impl" })

public class InsuranceCleanupServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InsuranceCleanupServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**DatabaseInteractionService startup class**

```
package com.dis;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.ms.base.entity")
public class DatabaseInteractionServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DatabaseInteractionServiceApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Value("spring.datasource.driverClassName")
    String driverClassName;
    
    @Value("spring.datasource.url")
    String url;
    
    
    @Value("spring.datasource.username")
    String username;
    
    @Value("spring.datasource.password")
    String password;
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate()
    {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
        jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }
}
```

I am using the Mysql database and Spring-data. When worked independently there seems no issue.
After separation, I am facing the below issue.

**Consider defining a bean of type 'com.dis.dao.EmployeeDao' in your configuration.**

Answer (score 1):

Why you have 2 `@SpringBootApplication` classes since one project will be used as dependency? It seems to me that `DatabaseInteractionServiceApplication` is more a `@Configuration` class rather than a `@SpringBootApplication`.

Apart from this the error

> *Consider defining a bean of type 'com.dis.dao.EmployeeDao' in your configuration*

means that somewhere you inject (@Autowire) a `EmployeeDao` bean but it doesn't exist in your Spring context. I suppose it exists in `InsuranceCleanupServiceApplication` project since there you have annotated:

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.ms.base.entity", "com.dis", "com.dis.config", "com.dis.dao", "com.dis.dao.Impl" })
```

`@EntityScan` annotation works only for `@Entity` annotated classes. If you want to scan for services/repositories/components you should change it to `@ComponentScan`. You need to add `@ComponentScan` since your `@SpringBootApplication` class belongs to a different package, `com.ics` than `com.dis` and as such it won't automatically pick up classes that are annotated with `@Service`, `@Component` or `@Repository` belonging to `com.dis` package. So I suppose just

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.dis"})
```

will suffice since it will also scan subpackages e.g. "com.dis.config", "com.dis.dao", "com.dis.dao.Impl"

Leave `@EntityScan` only for your entity package (it already exists in `DatabaseInteractionServiceApplication`):

```
@EntityScan("com.ms.base.entity")
```